# Can MethodHandle be used by frameworks/libraries (instead of traditional reflection)?

Tags: java, reflection, methodhandle

In my framework I have a class like this:

```
public class Foo<B, V> {
    private final Method getterMethod;
    ...

    public V executeGetter(B bean) {
        try {
           return getterMethod.invoke(bean);
        } catch ...
    }
}
```

This class is used to call getters of classes created by users that aren't available at compile time of my framework. For example, `B` might be a class called `Person`.

Through profiling, I've discovered that this method is horribly slow. The `Method.invoke()` takes 40% of performance in sampling profiling (even with `setAccessible(true)`), while a non reflective implementation takes only a small fraction of that performance.

**So I 'd like to replace is with a `MethodHandle`:**

```
public class Foo<B, V> {
    private final MethodHandle getterMethodHandle;
    ...

    public V executeGetter(B bean) {
        try {
           return getterMethodHandle.invoke(bean);
        } catch ...
    }
}
```

But then I get this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast [Ljava.lang.Object; to Person
    at sun.invoke.util.ValueConversions.newClassCastException(ValueConversions.java:461)
    at sun.invoke.util.ValueConversions.castReference(ValueConversions.java:456)
    at ...Foo.executeGetter(Foo.java:123)
```

even though `bean` is an instance of `Person`. Now the misleading part is that it's trying to cast an `Object[]` (and not an `Object`) to `Person`. Note that wrapping it in an object array (which is a performance loss) doesn't help:

```
 return getterMethodHandle.invoke(new Object[]{bean}); // Same exception
```

Is it possible to get the `MethodHandle` to work in this situation?

Comment: Can you add the full stacktrace?

Comment: How did you construct the `getterMethodHandle`?

Comment: Stacktrace added. Using JDK 7 for the record.

Comment: handle constructred like this: `getterMethodHandle = lookup.unreflect(getterMethod);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That `ClassCastException` only occurs if you compile with source/target level java 6.

**Compile with source/target level 7 or higher** to avoid that `ClassCastException`.

Answer found thanks to Tagir's answer. (vote up his answer too)

Answer (score 3):

Using MethodHandles in framework/library code is perfectly fine and I see no problem in your code. This example works just fine:

```
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodType;

public class Foo<B, V> {
    private final MethodHandle getterMethodHandle;

    public Foo(MethodHandle mh) {
        this.getterMethodHandle = mh;
    }

    public V executeGetter(B bean) {
        try {
           return (V) getterMethodHandle.invoke(bean);
        } catch(RuntimeException | Error ex) {
            throw ex;
        } catch(Throwable t) {
            throw new RuntimeException(t);
        }
    }

    static class Pojo {
        String x;

        public Pojo(String x) {
            this.x = x;
        }

        public String getX() {
            return x;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // I prefer explicit use of findXYZ
        Foo<Pojo, String> foo = new Foo<>(MethodHandles.lookup()
                .findVirtual(Pojo.class, "getX", MethodType.methodType(String.class)));
        // Though unreflect also works fine
        Foo<Pojo, String> foo2 = new Foo<>(MethodHandles.lookup()
                .unreflect(Pojo.class.getMethod("getX")));

        System.out.println(foo.executeGetter(new Pojo("foo")));
        System.out.println(foo2.executeGetter(new Pojo("bar")));
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
foo
bar
```

For even better performance consider using `invokeExact`, though it will not allow you automatic type conversions like unboxing.

Comment: Very interesting. You indeed don't compile time reference Pojo in the executeGetter method. I need to investigate why it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: In JDK 1.7 with source and target level Java 6, this exact code *throws the same exception*:
    `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast [Ljava.lang.Object; to org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.common.Foo$Pojo at ...Foo.executeGetter(Foo.java:34)`

Comment: And **with the same JDK (1.7) but source and target level Java 7 it does work** (unlike with source/target java 6).

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet, that's actually expected. There's special annotation `@PolymorphicSignature` on `invoke/invokeExact` methods which is specially handled by java compiler since Java 7, but such annotation means nothing when target is Java 6 or lower which results in incorrect bytecode generation.

Comment: Makes sense now, although JDK 7 should have failed fast if it's compiling any code that uses MethodHandles with a target level of java 6. Thanks! PS: [I am baffled again for another reason with methodhandles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34069386/methodhandle-to-a-getter-setter-from-another-class-gvies-a-nosuchfielderror)