# MethodHandle to a getter/setter from another class gives a NoSuchFieldError

Tags: java, reflection, methodhandle

Suppose I have simple javabean `MyPerson` with a `name` getter and setter:

```
public class MyPerson {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Now I am running this main code that simply gets and sets that `name` field:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
        MethodHandle getterMethodHandle = lookup.findGetter(MyPerson.class, "name", String.class);
        MethodHandle setterMethodHandle = lookup.findSetter(MyPerson.class, "name", String.class);
        MyPerson a = new MyPerson();
        a.setName("Batman");
        System.out.println("Name from getterMethodHandle: " + getterMethodHandle.invoke(a));
        setterMethodHandle.invoke(a, "Robin");
        System.out.println("Name after setterMethodHandle: " + a.getName());
    }
```

If I add that `main()` method on the class `MyPerson`, I get what I expect:

```
Name from getterMethodHandle: Batman
Name after setterMethodHandle: Robin
```

If I add **that same `main()` method on another class in another package**, I get this weird error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: no such field: batman.other.MyMain.name/java.lang.String/getField
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName.makeAccessException(MemberName.java:875)
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(MemberName.java:990)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.resolveOrFail(MethodHandles.java:1373)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.findGetter(MethodHandles.java:1022)
    at batman.other.MyMain.main(MyMain.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: name
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.resolve(Native Method)
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolve(MemberName.java:962)
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(MemberName.java:987)
```

Why? `MyPerson`'s getter/setters are public, so there's no reason why `MyMain` shouldn't be to use them, even through MethodHandles.

Using JDK 8 with source/target level java 8.

Comment: With JDK 1.8.0_51, the first snippet gives an error for me: `java.lang.IllegalAccessException: member is private: MyPerson.name/java.lang.String/getField`, which I think is expected.

Comment: @Tunaki for me java 1.8.0_51 it doesn't but the main() method inside the MyPerson class for me. If it's in another class in another package, I get the second exception. Haven't tried with a class in the same package.

Comment: The javadoc indicates that some access checking is performed so this might fail if the caller is not in the same package (and `MyPerson` should be in the same package as `MyPerson` ;) ). It might be the field being `private` (in which case only `MyPerson` should have access to it) or a security manager that prevents access to the field.

Comment: Btw, in 1.8.0_40 (but I assume this hasn't changed much) source shows that `getDirectField(REF_getField, refc, field)` is called by `findGetter` and the "direct" part indicates that it is not using the getter you provided but tries to directly read the field - and this should fail due to the field being private.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are mixing the things. What you need is:

```
MethodHandle getterMethodHandle = lookup.findVirtual(MyPerson.class,
        "getName", MethodType.methodType(String.class));
MethodHandle setterMethodHandle = lookup.findVirtual(MyPerson.class,
        "setName", MethodType.methodType(void.class, String.class));
```

The `findGetter` and `findSetter` methods do not try to find some getXXX or setXXX methods like in Java Beans. Don't forget that method handles are very low-level stuff. These methods actually build a method handle which does not point to an existing method, but just sets the field with given name. Using `findGetter` you don't need to have an actual getter method in your class, but you must have a direct access to the field. If you want to use the getter method like `getName`, you'll still need a `findVirtual` call.

In general method handles are much more powerful than just references to the methods. For example, you can bind method handle to one or several parameters, so you will not need to specify them on the invocation.

Comment: So I could bind one methodhandle per bean instance to speed things up? Interesting. Currently I haven't done that yet (as it's a major design change), but in this state, I am not seeing a performance gain, actually a big loss instead: [before](https://issues.jboss.org/secure/attachment/12395553/Selection_075.png] and [after](https://issues.jboss.org/secure/attachment/12395600/Selection_076.png) ([full jira log](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-483))

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet, actually you should not trust the profilers. I'm pretty sure their numbers are completely irrelevant and your bottleneck is probably in another place. Profilers sample at safepoints. The JIT-compiled code have safepoints not everywhere. No safepoints = wrong profiling data.

Comment: Interesting. So sampling profiling points to the wrong suspect and instrumation profiling unfairly slows down low level methods. :/

Comment: For the record: with profiler attached, methodhandles are also very noticeably slower than plain old reflection (but the methodhandles are used ad described above, no binding of parameters).

Answer (score 1):

If you check the documentation of [Lookup](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html), you will see that:

> Each method handle created by a factory method is the functional equivalent of a particular bytecode behavior

For example the getter lookup:

```
lookup.findGetter(C.class,"f",FT.class)
```

gets translated into:

```
 (T) this.f;
```

Hence the strange error `NoSuchFieldError: name`, as you were referencing a private field from outside. For getters/setters you should go for `findVirtual`.